# When to load my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, cordova

Does including javascript in a page, without executing it impede the browser (or specifically, my phone gap app) in anyway? My belief is having a few hundred kb of scripts itself is not problematic - the potential for problems is more likely when executing the code.

I am using PhoneGap with jQuery Mobile and a number of my own scripts. After obfusication, all javascript gets reduced in size to about 300kb.

I'm trying to decide if I should dynamically include my javascript when needed, or include it when the app is started. On some devices, dynamically including less used js could lead to a brief but noticeable pause in the app while the code is being loaded (either from locally, or across the net).

So... should I include from the start, or dynamically include as and when needed?

Comment: Depends on your needs and usages

Comment: Not 100% sure about mobile, but other browsers cache the js, so once it's been sent to the client, it doesn't need to be sent again.  Depending on how you do so, "dynamically" loading js will less likely be automatically cached.

Comment: This is clearly an opinion-based question, but as long as you're asking, my opinion is that a 300kb network delay has more of a user impact than unspecified "potential for problems when executing the code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include it when the app is started, as long as it is not too big (to my personal opinion 300kb is not, but again it can be circumstantial). That is only my opinion ofc.
In web apps, browsers cache js, so it won't be downloaded all the time. I don't know if that is the case with your application though.

Comment: I should have been more clear - I make the assumption that there is no cache (I assume that the app never ran previously). I do think that loading the code when the app is started is best, as the overhead of having some functions sit in memory and not be executed is less than the overhead of dynamically loading code later during execution.

Comment: I would use also use that approach - loading code when app is started. I am doing it for quite a few js files (though in web app).